# OpenStack HA Configuration problem missing file

Tags: openstack, haproxy, high-availability, pacemaker, corosync

according to the tutorial at https://www.golinuxcloud.com/configure-haproxy-in-openstack-high-availability/ trying to implement HA. I'm stuck at the step where I need to add a VIP alias to the /etc/httpd/conf.d/15-horizon_vhost.conf file that I don't have. Does anyone know where I have to put this? I work on the Stein edition.

Answer (score 0):

The process of HA implementation for OpenStack is quite simple. you need to setup a VIP on your loadbalancer machines and manage the VIP with a clustering tool like keepalived or pacemaker, so you have VIP where you have your haproxy up and running. actually you can skip that part and use something like below for haproxy config.

```
global
  chroot  /var/lib/haproxy
  daemon
  group  haproxy
  maxconn  4000
  pidfile  /var/run/haproxy.pid
  user  haproxy

defaults
  log  global
  maxconn  4000
  option  redispatch
  retries  3
  timeout  http-request 10s
  timeout  queue 1m
  timeout  connect 10s
  timeout  client 1m
  timeout  server 1m
  timeout  check 10s

 listen dashboard_cluster
  bind 172.16.64.151:443
  balance  source
  option  tcpka
  option  httpchk
  option  tcplog
  server controller1 172.16.64.138:443 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
  server controller2 172.16.64.139:443 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
  server controller3 172.16.64.129:443 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5

 listen galera_cluster
  bind 172.16.64.151:3306
  balance  source
  option  mysql-check
  server galera1 172.16.64.136:3306 check port 9200 inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
  server galer2a 172.16.64.137:3306 backup check port 9200 inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5

 listen glance_api_cluster
  bind 172.16.64.151:9292
  balance  source
  option  tcpka
  option  httpchk
  option  tcplog
  server controller1 172.16.64.138:9292 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
  server controller2 172.16.64.139:9292 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
  server controller3 172.16.64.129:9292 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5

 listen glance_registry_cluster
  bind 172.16.64.151:9191
  balance  source
  option  tcpka
  option  tcplog
  server controller1 172.16.64.138:9191 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
  server controller2 172.16.64.139:9191 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
  server controller3 172.16.64.129:9191 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5

 listen keystone_admin_cluster
  bind 172.16.64.151:35357
  balance  source
  option  tcpka
  option  httpchk
  option  tcplog
  server controller1 172.16.64.138:35357 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
  server controller2 172.16.64.139:35357 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
  server controller3 172.16.64.129:35357 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5

 listen keystone_public_internal_cluster
  bind 172.16.64.151:5000
  balance  source
  option  tcpka
  option  httpchk
  option  tcplog
  server controller1 172.16.64.138:5000 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
  server controller2 172.16.64.139:5000 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
  server controller3 172.16.64.129:5000 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5

 listen nova_ec2_api_cluster
  bind 172.16.64.151:8773
  balance  source
  option  tcpka
  option  tcplog
  server controller1 172.16.64.138:8773 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
  server controller2 172.16.64.139:8773 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
  server controller3 172.16.64.129:8773 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5

 listen nova_compute_api_cluster
  bind 172.16.64.151:8774
  balance  source
  option  tcpka
  option  tcplog
  server controller1 172.16.64.138:8774 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
  server controller2 172.16.64.139:8774 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
  server controller3 172.16.64.129:8774 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5

 listen nova_metadata_api_cluster
  bind 172.16.64.151:8775
  balance  source
  option  tcpka
  option  tcplog
  server controller1 172.16.64.138:8775 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
  server controller2 172.16.64.139:8775 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
  server controller3 172.16.64.129:8775 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5

listen nova_placement_cluster
  bind 172.16.64.151:8778
  balance  source
  option  tcpka
  option  tcplog
  server controller1 172.16.64.138:8778 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
  server controller2 172.16.64.139:8778 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
  server controller3 172.16.64.129:8778 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5

 listen cinder_api_cluster
  bind 172.16.64.151:8776
  balance  source
  option  tcpka
  option  httpchk
  option  tcplog
  server controller1 172.16.64.138:8776 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
  server controller2 172.16.64.139:8776 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
  server controller3 172.16.64.129:8776 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5

 listen ceilometer_api_cluster
  bind 172.16.64.151:8777
  balance  source
  option  tcpka
  option  tcplog
  server controller1 172.16.64.138:8777 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
  server controller2 172.16.64.139:8777 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
  server controller3 172.16.64.129:8777 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5

 listen nova_vncproxy_cluster
  bind 172.16.64.151:6080
  balance  source
  option  tcpka
  option  tcplog
  server controller1 172.16.64.138:6080 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
  server controller2 172.16.64.139:6080 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
  server controller3 172.16.64.129:6080 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5

 listen neutron_api_cluster
  bind 172.16.64.151:9696
  balance  source
  option  tcpka
  option  httpchk
  option  tcplog
  server controller1 172.16.64.138:9696 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
  server controller2 172.16.64.139:9696 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
  server controller3 172.16.64.129:9696 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5

 listen swift_proxy_cluster
  bind 172.16.64.151:8080
  balance  source
  option  tcplog
  option  tcpka
  server controller1 172.16.64.138:8080 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
  server controller2 172.16.64.139:8080 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
  server controller3 172.16.64.129:8080 check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5
```